# ModulNotFoundError even though !pip freeze tells you it is downloaded on ubuntu through WSL

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

I am using Ubuntu18.04 through Windows Subsystems for Linux(WSL)

on ubuntu I run jupyter lab and try to import libraries however even though `!pip freeze` command states that all libraries are installed outputs `ModulNotFoundError`

Everything works find on python script when I run `main.py` it imports all dependencies without a problem.

When I run jupyter lab on ubuntu with WSL it seems like it doesn't bring dependencies with it, how can I fix it?? Weird thing is !pip freeze inside jupyter lab tells me I have all dependencies installed.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
When I install package on jupyter lab it says `Requirements already satisfied` . Also this only happens when I spin up jupyter lab on virtual env. When I run on global environment it seems to work fine.

EDIT2: it seems to work with jupyter notebook.... not really sure why though and would love to know the reason if anyone is knowledgeable of this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `pip` executable might be pointing the a different version of python than what you're currently using in your notebook.

You might try running pip using the `%pip` magic function instead of running the inline shell command `!pip`, i.e.

```py
%pip freeze
```

and

```py
%pip install your-missing-package
```

---

#### Explanation

`%pip` is a line-magic function that uses the current executable (`sys.executable`).

In contrast, `!anycommand ...` runs the shell command:

```sh
sh anycommand ...
```

using the old-school `sh` shell interpreter (not `bash` as you might expect). Therefore, it is possible that the system executable `pip` that you're running (via `!pip ...`) uses a different version of python from `sys.executable`.

---

#### Alternative

Alternatively, if this doesn't work, you could use `sys.executable` in your shell command (in a notebook cell):

```py
import sys

!{sys.executable} -m pip freeze
```

Similarly, to install packages, you might want to run:

```py
!{sys.executable} -m pip install your-missing-package
```

Comment: Thanks Kris. I will try your method and let you know once I fix my jupyter lab... for some reason it is current not working.